# Where can I find the Spotify 'Apps Flow' document mentioned in the Spotify integration guidelines?

Tags: spotify, doc

In the following section of the [integration guidelines](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/guidelines/01_integration-guidelines.html#signingintoyourownservice), a document called App flows is referenced.

Do anybody know where I can find this "App flows" document?
Or at least some more information about external logins.

Answer (score 0):

The guidelines are outdated. The flows doc isn't necessary. A new version of the guidelines is coming.